# calculate logarithm for very large numbers

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, sign, logarithm, largenumber

I would like to calculate the following function for very large number (for example e^e^e^e^10) and would like to know the sign of the following term in general. I tried for some numbers, but it is  negative. Is there any m0 such that for all n>m>m0, the following function is positive.

where n is greater than m.

I tied with Mathematica, but it does not compute for the above number. Should I use special package?

thanks

[image]

Comment: you should take this here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com